# Can I uninstall older versions of Java?

Tags: java

I have just noices that I have too many versions of Java installed in my system:

[image]

Can I ask older versions of Java from my computer without worrying about some other softwares stop working in my computer?

Comment: There is always a chance that specific software won't work with newer versions which is the reason you will have to make sure they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. You should uninstall all older versions of Java.

There is an Java recommendation about this - http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml

Answer (score 1):

Of course. There should be absolutely no problem uninstalling all older versions. You should only use the latest version anyway (especially if they're all some iteration of Java 7/1.7). Same goes for the JDK.

Oracle provide an [uninstaller tool](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/uninstaller_toolinfo.xml) to simplify this.